# React-Native ListView causing error from GraphQL result

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

New to React-native I was hoping the following would work based on information I have seen around `ListView`.

When I run the app in an Android Emulator I get the follwoing error

[image]

Just before the error I see a warning...

[image]

The code on this page is...

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { View, Text, ListView } from 'native-base';

import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

class RootContainer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <MatchData />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class MatchView extends Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.data.loading) {
            return (<Text>Loading...</Text>)
        }
        else {
            if (this.props.data.error) {
                return (<Text>error: {JSON.stringify(this.props.data.error)}</Text>)
            } else {
                return (<ListView
                    dataSource={this.props.data.getMatchList}
                    renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>}
                    />)
            }
        }
    }

}

MatchView.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
        loading: PropTypes.bool,
        error: React.PropTypes.object,
        getMatchList: PropTypes.array
    }).isRequired
};

const QueryMatches = gql`
    query templates { 
        getMatchList {
            id,
            name, 
        } 
    }
`;

const MatchData = graphql(QueryMatchList)(MatchView)

export default RootContainer;
```

The part of the code that is not working is:

```
return (<ListView
   dataSource={this.props.data.getMatchList}
   renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.name}</Text>}
/>
```

The result from `getMatchList` is a standard array from the graphQL response. If I remove the `ListView` altogether no error or warning is displayed (if I replace it with just dummy text... `<Text>it works</Text>`)

Not sure what is going wrong here.

Could it need converting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

Since I was using `native-base` the `ListView` is actually `List` and `ListItem`. So the answer is...

[List native-base docs](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#list)

```
import {
    View,
    Text,
    List,
    ListItem,
} from 'native-base';
```

with the render method as:

```
return (<List dataArray={this.props.data.getMatchList}
                renderRow={(item) =>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                }>
            </List>
```

Looks like the error is pretty generic within the observer.